# Are scopes necessary for accessing a corporate trusted API from a trusted application?

Tags: azure, authentication, security

When using Azure AD to secure applications, is it necessary to have the API also registered in AD, with scopes being exposed to the client app?

This is an internal company app, so there is no requirement to have users consent or decline to using the service.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call an Azure AD secured API on behalf of a user, you need at least one scope.
In case of internal APIs, you can define just one scope and have an admin consent to that scope on the client app.
This way users will not be asked to consent to it.

Comment: Thank you. What’s the benefit in creating the scope for an internal API and is it even necessary to register the API application on AD?

Comment: Well you probably want some kind of authentication on the API? You can use the same app registration for both the API and front-end to if you'd like.

Comment: What would be the difference between using the same app registration and having a different one? I am not clear about the benefit in registering the API at all, given that the access token will contain information that I can configure the service to look up - eg check the client id matches or issuer matches etc.

Comment: Does registering and linking the api to the client registration provide any more security? If so how.

Comment: Well, the main thing is that in order to use OAuth/OpenID Connect _correctly_, you should always use an access token to call an API, not an ID token. To acquire an access token, you need a scope. This scope has to be on an app registration. Using the same app registration I would recommend if the front-end and API are part of the same app. This didn't use to be possible, they had to be separate in the past.